# "Published on ..." or "Published ..."?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, dates

So, in an article on a web-page, I want to provide information about the date when the article was published. I am not sure if there should be an "on" after the word "published".

> Article title...
>
> Published...
>
> Article text...

So, below the article title, should I write:

> Published on January 1st 2012

or

> Published January 1st 2012

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either:

> Published on 14th Jan 2012

or

> Published: 14th Jan 2012

as @incognito and @Irene have already highlighted.

But since you are making a web page, I think its better in stick to the convention used by most.

Wordpress uses *posted on* , as you can see:

---

[image: Wordpress uses "posted on"]

While both Facebook, Blogger and Typepad just mention the date, in a slightly faded font:

---

[image: Blogger just mentions the date]

Overall, I think just mentioning the date in a slightly faded or smaller font is more popular among web-sites, so I think you should adopt this convention.

Answer (score 2):

I can't help noticing that there are three answers here already, every one of which suggests that the only alternative to the word *"on"* would be to add a semicolon after the word *"Published"*.

I disagree with this, and [here are millions of examples](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=%22published%3a+1st%22&pbx=1&oq=%22published%3a+1st%22&aq=f&aqi=g-v1g-j1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=8987l8987l2l9440l1l1l0l0l0l0l187l187l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4c26890357e371b1&biw=1262&bih=764) for *"Published 1st [some monthname]"* showing that you don't need anything at all. In fact, I personally believe that in general the colon looks "geeky" - it's reminiscent of screen-based computer input forms many decades ago.

My position is that whilst there's nothing wrong with using the word *"on"*, there's also nothing wrong with *not* using it. But there *is* something a bit flaky about replacing it with a colon.

Comment: OK, got it. English is a flexible language.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: I notice you have a couple of colons on your ELU user profile page. And of course I've just used one there after your user name. But I don't think those examples are really to do with *language* (be it English, Croatian, or whatever) - they're more about "page layout". Specifically, in a computer/webpage context, where we have all sorts of other features available (type size, font, colour). You should just trust your own instincts about whether the layout is informative and uncluttered - or maybe ask on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-development

Comment: Well, my question is not about semicolon usage. I was just unsure if "on" could be omitted from the expression. So, it seems that both "*Published on (date)*" and "*Published (date)*" are fine. That's for instance not true in German and Croatian. (In German, a preposition must be used - "*Veröffentlicht **am** ersten Januar, 2012*", and in Croatian a preposition must not be be used - "*Objavljeno prvog siječnja, 2012*".) So, as I said, English is flexible here...

Comment: Sorry about that - I forgot that the only reason I answered in the first place was because all the other three answers slipped a colon in to replace the word "on". You're quite right - English is indeed flexible on this point, both in speech *and* writing (even "formal" prose, not just "cut-down webpage grammar"). It's interesting that German and Croatian have more fixed rules, one of each type.

Answer (score 0):

For the format you require, the best option is:

*Published:* ...(date)

It is advisable to follow the same format in the other pieces of information you will include, i.e:

*Article title:* ...

*Article text:* ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of them.

> Published on 14th Jan 2012

OR

> Published: 14th Jan 2012

A colon after published will be meaningful and somewhat required, in case you want to use second option.